# How to convert this Python to C++ without overflow?

Tags: c++, python, overflow

I have the following Python snippet

```
v=(2*(a/2)+1)**2
U=int(((4*N+v)**.5-1)/4)
```

N is on the order of 10^12, and the variable "a" takes on many values but is also of 10^12 magnitude at its largest.

However I can't seem to write this in C++ without overflowing something somewhere and I am a little stuck.

edit: And yes, the 2*(a/2) is intentional because in Python, division is the same as floor division. Sometimes a is odd so I need to halve it, floor it, then remultiply it by 2, which is what that code does.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is my code -- it is what I am trying to translate to C++. Unless you mean my C++ code, in which case I just tried using long longs and it wasn't able to hold everything.

Comment: Do you want floats? Or [even longer integers](http://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: I tried installing GMP a long time ago but I found it notoriously difficult to get working on Windows, and even then it was really cumbersome to work with. The resulting values I am after are integers (in the mathematical sense) as opposed to decimal/floating point. The U=int() part just cuts off any decimal chunk as it isn't needed for my program.

Comment: For instance, for a=10^12, v is 4000004000001 and U is 707106

Comment: @KaliMa: Whether you like it or not, the with such numbers if you want a precise answer you will need a big integer library, or you can use `double` and loose precission. The value of `v` is in the range of 10^24, which is way higher than any integer that common platforms have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a=10**12
>>> v=(2*(a/2)+1)**2
>>> log(v,2)
79.72627427729958
```

The value you're calculating needs 80 bits, and a long long is only 64. You'll need an extended arithmetic package to handle it.

Comment: Aaauuuughh. GMP is such a pain to work with. Can't get anything working 85% of the time. Thanks though.

Comment: It's actually pretty easy [from C++](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html).

Comment: How do you know you aren't losing precision in the Python version already? `(4*N+v)**.5` returns a float, even for `N` = 1 and `v` = 0.

Comment: @mkb it is not so imprecise that the integer value of the result will be off. My value of N would need to be much, much larger for that to happen

Comment: Also, how do I set a GMP variable to multiply from two vars? I am trying mpz_mul(v, ha, ha); where ha is the (2*(a/2)+1)^2 result as a long long, v being a mpz_class